# Injecting javascript into page via url

Tags: javascript, html, webview

I'm trying to run a javascript code via url to change values of the form in the page.
Here is the content of the HTML page.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method='post'>
Name: <input type='text' id='name' value='' /><br />
Family: <input type='text' id='family' value='' /><br />
Email: <input type='text' id='email' value='' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I enter the following value in the URL section of chrome:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('name').value = 'string1';
```

What happens is my whole page will go blank and only the value "string1" will be displayed in the page.
However, running the following code works properly:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('name').value = 1;
```

It will change the value of the name field to 1.
I'm wondering what is causing this problem.

Note: The purpose of this work is to inject code into webview in android.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: works fine in jsfiddle on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/kscqdsw0/

Comment: In firefox, chrome and android webview, it has the same issue.

Comment: do you wait for document ready? because I think the error lies there.

Comment: The script works fine if I write it as a script tag in the html page.
The issue is when I enter the code in the URL section of the chrome.
You can check it here:
http://hamed.afshar.ir/temp/acharge.php
you open this url, when it loaded completely, you enter the following code in URL section of the browser and you see what happens:
javascript:document.getElementById('name').value = 'string1';

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
javascript:document.getElementById('name').value = 'string1'; undefined;
```

Tack on a 'undefined;' to any script that returns a string.

Answer (score -1):

That is because you are using single quotes after the attribute value

```
value=''
```

and you changing it's value in javascript using

```
document.getElementById('name').value='string1';
```

so the html becomes

```
<input type='text' id='name' value=''string1''
```

you can fix it using

```
value=""
```

or using

```
document.getElementById('name').value="string1";
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I changed the html to double quotes or script to double quotes, or both to double quotes, but all three failed and didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

well i tried the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<form method='post'>
Name: <input type='text' id='name' value='' /><br />
Family: <input type='text' id='family' value='' /><br />
Email: <input type='text' id='email' value='' /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
</form>
<button onclick="change()">Click me</button>
<script>
function change(){
var obj=document.getElementById('name');
obj.value="string1";

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it works just fine the problem is in your script
do you created a function to change the value or just putted the code in a script tag like this

```
<script>document.getElementById('name').value="String1";<script>
```